# Warning: Missing argument 1 for MyCompany\CmsBundle\Controller\DocumentDuplicateController::__construct

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, doctrine

I am working on an app based on Symfony 2.7.

I want to inject the Doctrine service to my controller, and I want to pass it as a service constructor in order to avoid relying on the whole container. So I put the following in my services.yml file:

```
  app.controller.document_duplicate:
    class: MyCompany\CmsBundle\Controller\DocumentDuplicateController
    arguments:
      - "@doctrine"
```

... and I put the following in my controller class:

```
public function __construct($doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}
```

... which does not behave as I expect it to. When I view the controller in a brower, I get an exception:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   MyCompany\CmsBundle\Controller\DocumentDuplicateController::__construct(),
>   called in
>   /usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
>   on line 194 and defined

**What do I need to fix in order to let the controller see the service that I'm trying to pass to it?**

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I just had to put this annotation above my class definition in order to get it to pay attention to the contents of the services.yml file:

```
/**
 * @Route(service="app.controller.document_duplicate")
 */
```

That did the trick.